# SuperTuxKart 0.9.3-2 has no online multiplayer?

Tags: games

SuperTuxKart on disco dingo has no local multiplayer or local networking options ? I would love to play online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Online Multiplayer appear in SuperTuxKart 1.0

Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo = SuperTuxKart 0.9.3

Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan Ermine = SuperTuxKart 1.0

For now you can install the snap version https://snapcraft.io/supertuxkart or the PPA for Disco Dingo https://launchpad.net/~stk/+archive/ubuntu/dev?field.series_filter=disco

Alternatively you can download it in your /home without installing. https://sourceforge.net/projects/supertuxkart/ Check the "README" file to see all dependent packages that you need to install. Open a terminal in the game directory and run ./run_game.sh to execute the game.

Comment: thank you. this community is one of the reasons i switched over to linux. you guys rock